# Help me find the torsion subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wanna find the torsion subgroup $T$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C^*}$ of  nonzero complex numbers. Please show me solving process. Solution is $\{ e ^{q \pi\ i} \mid q \in\ \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z \in \text{Tor }(\mathbb{C}^*)$ be an element of finite order.

Express $z$ in polar form as $z=r \exp(i \theta)$. Since $\text{ord} (z)=n<\infty$, we have 
$$z^n=r^n \exp( in \theta)=1 .$$

Taking the modulus of this gives $r^n=1$ which means $r=1$.

Taking the argument of both sides gives $n \theta=\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $\arg z=\theta=\pi k/n$.

We have just proved the inclusion $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}^*) \subseteq \{ \exp(q \pi i) | q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. The reversed inclusion is much easier.